# Real time location broadcast

Tags: android, mysql, google-api

I'm developping an android cab booking app , My goal is that all registered users on the passenger app can see the location of all near by cabs in a realtime map ,when they click the cab marker they can see information about the cab , driver ,distance...then send a request to driver

the geolocalisation of the cabs must be done through the driver smartphones , the drivers have also their own app and they must be registered .
for I made a registration system with PHP/MySQL, It't supposed after login into the app to show a map with current location in it (passenger's location) and all near by cabs.
My question is how can I broadcast and show the registered drivers' locations to all registered passengers maps ??

Comment: try to get  location of driver when they open app and save in server db. Now when passenger open app fetch record from db and show marker in app

Comment: Split it into two: the drivers: live map of cabs and passengers. The passengers: Live map of the vabs. As @Divyesh said, use a database on a server and fetch the appropriate data.

Comment: But it should be a real time location , what happened if the driver moves !!

Comment: then use firebase realtime datasbse

Comment: actually ,I've tried it but it was very difficult for me to use it , this is my graduation project and I'm running out of time , I cannot spend more time learning how to use it , isn't there another suggestion please !

Comment: I have send location to server , but when I tryed to fetch the records I didn't know how to store them in my activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver apps should send their locations to the server  and should be saved in mysql which are updated every certain period of time as you had chosen in your driver app using the method (onLocationChanged(Location location)).

When the passenger open his app it also sends his location to the server which will select for him the nearest  drivers for instance the nearest five using (google distance matrix api) which you can call through your php server using curl . Also the location of passenger should be saved in database and updated in the same way to show to drivers .

Comment: Thanks a lot ,I will try it , do you have any tutorial that can help !! sorry for bothering

Comment: I made something similar , so I can help at anytime if u needed anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I realllly appreciate it :)

Comment: Sir , I followed what you've said : I 've managed sending data (lang and lat) to the server and updating them periodically ( every 5 seconds) ,I've used Volley library by the way .But, when it comes to retreiving all drivers' locations in real time and store all the records in my activity I got quite confused how and what type should I use to store them ??

Comment: Hi Naisy, as I understood from you you want to show in the passenger app the nearest drivers so in the same method that return the passenger location, send the location to the server side use this location with the locations of drivers to decide which are the nearest drivers use this api to decide 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro
then only send to the passenger the drivers who are far by less than a pre configured distance

Comment: Mr Daniel Raouf, thank you very much, I followed what you've said and it worked. Now, I want the passenger to be able to send a request to one of the drivers (with a button click on the popup window that shows when he clicks on the marker). I've been looking for a while and I found out GCM, but they mostly use firebase, and I already developped my app with MySQL another problem I only found them in push notification or Chat Apps (multiple users instead of only two) ,can you guide me here plz.

Comment: Firebase is the best solution for push notifications , you can send notifications from your back end  using firebase APIs which you can find it here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message.
But you should also add firebase to the drivers app and get a firebase token every new registeration which you should save in your db so that you can send them notifications after that

Comment: How can you handle massive of data in your db ?? after a while we will have thousands of passengers and drivers . All of data should be store in db ??!!!